# Force Specific Struct Size in C

Tags: c, memory, struct, sizeof, system

For various reasons, I have some structs I want to force to be specific sizes (in this case 64 bytes and 512 bytes). Both however, are below the somewhat below the sizes I want them to be.

Is there anyway for me to tell the compiler to set them to these specific sizes and pad with zeros, or would I be best off just declaring an array inside the struct that makes up the excess space so that it aligns on the size I want?

Comment: What are the reasons?  There may be another way to solve the problem.

Comment: using unions with an array of chars comes to mind...

Comment: You could try some sort of hack with `#pragma pack`, but I don't know how useful this will be.

Comment: I'm doing some low level stuff for an OS class, and the block size is 512 bytes when I read from disk. I could just have a scratch area where I read in blocks, but I thought it'd be more elegant to make critical data structs be block_size so that I can read straight to them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a union.

```
struct mystruct_s {
    ... /* who knows how long */
};

typedef union {
    struct mystruct_s s;
    unsigned char padding[512];
} mystruct;
```

This will ensure the union is 512 bytes or more.  Then, you can ensure that it is no more than 512 bytes using a static assertion somewhere in your code:

```
/* Causes a compiler error if sizeof(mystruct) != 512 */
char array[sizeof(mystruct) != 512 ? -1 : 1];
```

If you are using C11, there is a better way to do this.  I don't know anybody who uses C11 yet.  The standard was published a matter of weeks ago.

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(mystruct) == 512, "mystruct must be 512 bytes");
```

Note that the only way to pad with *zeroes* is to put the zeroes there manually (`calloc` or `memset`).  The compiler ignores padding bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's any way to automatize this, at least in gcc which is the compiler I use. You have to pad your structs.

Be careful about [automatic alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) of variables in your struct. For example
    struct example{
        char a;
        int b;
    }

does not take 5 bytes, but 8.