# Struct size/alignment

Tags: c, memory-alignment

How is a `struct` in C sized? For example with the below:

```
struct Person {
    char* name;
    char age;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct Person person1;
    person1.name = "John Smith";
    person1.age = 40;
    printf("The size of the Person object is: %lu.\n", sizeof(person1));
}
```

This gives me a size of `16` and not `9`. How is a `struct` aligned then or is it dependent on the architecture or C implementation? For example, is it on 16-byte boundaries, 8-byte boundaries, etc.?

Comment: Very likely you're on a 64-bit system where "words" (in the CPU sense) and pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes).

Comment: It is implementation dependent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see -- so all `struct`s will round up to the next multiple of word-size?

Comment: And if you want to learn the offsets (position) of members inside the structure, use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro.

Comment: It depends on the compiler and the target hardware. But for your specific system then probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's architecture dependent.  But you usually can control the size or alignment through attributes.  If you packed the structure via a pragma, you could make the size 9 bytes (assuming an 8 byte pointer).

See [C struct size alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130109/c-struct-size-alignment)

Comment: But you run the risk of dramatically impacting the efficiency. Iterating over a block of memory on 9-byte boundaries will be much slower than 16-byte boundaries.

Comment: This is definitely true.  I mentioned how to get the specific sizes.  There can also be problems with unaligned data access on certain architectures.  Packing a structure is very usage dependent.