# Instantiating multiple structs in C?

Tags: c, struct

What does the 100 specify in the following definition of a struct in C?

```
struct node_type 
{ float data;
  int next;
} node[100];
```

I wrote the following code to determine if it was [forcing a specific struct size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705665/force-specific-struct-size-in-c), but that's not the case (both returned a size of 8 bytes). Is it defining 100 instances of a node struct? If so, where are they being stored/how can they be accessed? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node_type{
  float data;
  int next;
}node[100];

int main(){

  struct node_type node = {21.9, 2};

  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(node)); // 8
  printf("%ld\n", sizeof(struct node_type)); // 8

}
```

Comment: Name is a duplicate.
Let's put a different name.

Comment: It defines an array of 100 `struct node_type`s named `node` in the global scope. You can just access it like any other array as long as `node` is visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that you are declaring array of 100 elements, where each element is of type `struct node_type`.

Note that local `node` identifier shadows external one, so it's no longer an array in block scope of `main` function. There is no way in C to access `node` array, unless `}` punctuator, that represents end of this block scope is encountered.